# Gmail filter "has the word" stopped working?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I am receiving emails with test results from overnight automation testing. I used different filters to label all testing emails. One of them is to make failed email with red label—easy to see if anything went wrong.

The filter "subject" = "EduTester" & "Has the words" = "fail" **stopped working for some** emails.

Even if I search for the word "fail" using the search box the emails that 100% contain the word are not found.

Going through my emails I can see that this stopped working on around 20.9.2012

My Ruby scripts generate the emails and I send them as plain text and also as HTML.

If I go to "Show original" of the email that wasn't found by both the filter & search and search for "fail" string, I get like 20 hits of fail. For example `<BR>Overall&nbsp;result:&nbsp;fail<BR>`

Any idea how to fix that?

## **update**

the exported filter looks like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>
    <title>Mail Filters</title>
    <id>tag:mail.google.com,2008:filters:1348814923241</id>
    <updated>2012-10-03T02:29:35Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name>Radek</name>
        <email>radek@com</email>
    </author>
    <entry>
        <category term='filter'></category>
        <title>Mail Filter</title>
        <id>tag:mail.google.com,2008:filter:1348814923241</id>
        <updated>2012-10-03T02:29:35Z</updated>
        <content></content>
        <apps:property name='subject' value='EDUtester'/>
        <apps:property name='hasTheWord' value='fail'/>
        <apps:property name='label' value='testing/EDUtester/failed'/>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: Did you confirm that the two parts of the search/filter work? Does the filer find emails with the expected subject and emails with the "has the words" part only.

Comment: In my question I said that `Even if I search for the word "fail" using the search box the emails that 100% contain the word are not found.` which is very strange. It used to work. How come the search won't find emails with a word that is obviously in the body?

Answer (score 3):

Two huge *"secrets"* to designing any truly powerful Google search are parenthesis `()` and curly brackets `{}`.  Anything that is wrapped in parenthesis will do the same thing as searching with the terms using the **AND** operator.  For example `(pie cherry)` will search for results that contain BOTH *pie* AND *cherry*.  On the other side of things using curly brackets will give your results using the **OR** operator.  For example `{black white}` will search for results that contain EITHER *black* OR *white* OR BOTH *black* and *white*

Within Gmail you can simple type the search into your search bar and then click the arrow at the right of the box which should expand to give you other options to narrow the search.  Disregard the body of the expanded box and look at the bottom right corner and click on the *"Create filter with this search"* link.

So I would try to put in `(subject:(EduTester) fail)` for your search and then create the filter from this.

Sample expanded search box:
[image: Sample expanded search box.]

Comment: The thing is that even searching using the search box doesn't find the emails that contain the text :-(

Comment: Did you try to the search with the brackets, just to check if it makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, I did try. `fail` , (fail) and {fail} gives me the same result.

Comment: I know this sounds pretty obvious but at the top of the expanded search box it allows you to set the scope of the search.  Have you double checked to ensure that it is indeed searching all mail and not just a subset?

Comment: I did double check now - all mail. When searching for 'fail' the kind of emails that are not found now are found before the 20.9.2012.

Comment: Such a specific date that completely changes the results would be the results of a Date search restriction in place.  Could you check the date category to make sure that it is not set?

If it is indeed not set then could you go to your filters, select this filter and the click on export.  It should give you an XML formatted file of the filter that you could post for us to take a look at and then we may be able to find the problem from there.

Comment: Added the exported filter to my question.

Comment: Your filter looks to be correct and at this point I am unsure what could really be the problem.  The only thing further that I can suggest is to try to delete this filter and try to recreate it.  Beyond that I do have to admit that I am out of other options.

Comment: What does `{&nbsp;fail}` return (try without the brackets). I tested on my archive of 6+ years of Gmails and I get different results than with `{fail}` -- there is a difference. Furthermore, the former results don't actually have the `&nbsp;fail` inside the "viewed source" of the email...

Comment: Nor `{&nbsp;fail}` or &nbsp;fail helped. I was investigating this bit more and ... I send the emails from my ruby application. When I do not send the body as html it is ok.

Comment: What MIME encoding are you using for the body?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: `----==_mimepart_50742a37368d6_80c15b8b484668f
Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2012 00:44:23 +1100
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <50742a373a5c6_80c15b8b48468bc@Yogurt.mail>` did it answer your question? I use ruby's gem named pony with default settings so I do know what MIME encoding is used. I copied some lines  from original email.

Comment: I upgraded ruby and maybe pony (not  100% sure) about the time when  this gmail labeling issue appeared.

Comment: I was thinking that MIME encoding would affect how the non-breaking space would appear. I'm not sure if Gmail groks the MIME encoding when it does searches in the content.